# Zero view, one answer? How is it possible?

Tags: support, questions, answers

I recently got stuck on this:
[image: Zero view, one answer]

How is that possible?

Comment: I've seen the view counter take a minute or two to update before, its probably all cached data.

Comment: What's weird is the view count on Area51. Why hasn't that updated yet?

Comment: I would of thought the cache flushing mechanism for the views would be at the same time as the answer and the votes, why would you need to separate them ?

Comment: @RobertPitt, totally agree. Still listening...

Comment: Mine just got 2 votes and 1 view :)

Comment: @s.m, It's just Jeff's power to double-vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43751/a-bug-in-the-views-calculation-views-0-time/43752#43752) on meta.SO view count updates are buffered (not written to the db right away) so it's not unusual for the view count to be a little behind, especially for a question that was just posted.